# same selector for different types data in web scraping using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm a **novice web developer** and have started coding recently.

I'm only familiar with **HTML/CSS/JS & NODE**.

I'm currently working on a **page scraper project** and **using puppeteer**

**PROBLEM** -
In code scenarios like this ↓ where there is the **same selector for different types data**. 
(which in this case is - **a[rel="tag"]** ).

```
<span class="clip-link">

  <h4>Stars:</h4>
  <a href="https://www.media.com/ACTORS/darshan-raval/" rel="tag">Darshan Raval</a>,
  <a href="https://www.media.com/ACTORS/priyanka-chopra/" rel="tag">Priyanka Chopra</a>
  <h4>Singers:</h4>
  <a href="https://www.media.com/SINGERS/hardy-sandhu/" rel="tag">Hardy Sandhu</a>,
  <a href="https://www.media.com/SINGERS/amit-trivedi/" rel="tag">Amit Trivedi</a>,
</span>
```

OR

```
<span class="clip-link">

  <h4>Stars:</h4>
  <a href="https://www.media.com/ACTORS/darshan-raval/" rel="tag">Darshan Raval</a>,
  <a href="https://www.media.com/ACTORS/priyanka-chopra/" rel="tag">Priyanka Chopra</a>,
  <a href="https://www.media.com/ACTORS/amir-khan/" rel="tag">Amir Khan</a>
  <h4>Singers:</h4>
  <a href="https://www.media.com/SINGERS/hardy-sandhu/" rel="tag">Hardy Sandhu</a>,
  <a href="https://www.media.com/SINGERS/amit-trivedi/" rel="tag">Amit Trivedi</a>,
</span>
```

The **only common difference we can see in these  tags is in their URL, just after the domain name.**

**QUESTION** -

**How do I select, and categorize these  tags based on URL-difference** (".com/ACTORS/." or ".com/SINGERS.") **and then get the innerText** of the element to store them like.

```json
actors = ["Darshan Raval","Priyanka Chopra"]
singers = ["Hardy Sandhu","Amit Trivedi"]
```

OR

```json
actors = ["Darshan Raval","Priyanka Chopra","Amir Khan"]
singers = ["Hardy Sandhu","Amit Trivedi"]
```

The number of "Stars" and "Singers" are different all the time, so I can't define I fixed array count method.

Comment: Run a full HREF grab on the site and loop through them and do a regex match for exactly the site pre-fix and if a match occurs, scoop the innerText and build two new arrays one for actors and one for singers.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's a question here.

Comment: @pguardiario Thanks for your response. I've edited the question so it can be more clear.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't see any puppeteer code or a concrete attempt/example to work with here. Can you clarify the issue with your current code? Thanks.

Comment: @Avisha, I'm expecting to see a sentence that ends in a question mark and that's not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
      <span class="clip-link">
        <h4>Stars:</h4>
        <a href="https://www.media.com/ACTORS/darshan-raval/" rel="tag">Darshan Raval</a>,
        <a href="https://www.media.com/ACTORS/priyanka-chopra/" rel="tag">Priyanka Chopra</a>,
        <a href="https://www.media.com/ACTORS/amir-khan/" rel="tag">Amir Khan</a>
        <h4>Singers:</h4>
        <a href="https://www.media.com/SINGERS/hardy-sandhu/" rel="tag">Hardy Sandhu</a>,
        <a href="https://www.media.com/SINGERS/amit-trivedi/" rel="tag">Amit Trivedi</a>,
      </span>
    </body>
  </html>`;

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const tags = [...document.querySelectorAll('a[rel="tag"]')];
    return tags.reduce((persons, tag) => {
      const type = tag.pathname.split('/')[1];
      persons[type] ??= [];
      persons[type].push(tag.innerText);
      return persons;
    }, {});
  });
  console.log(data);
} catch (err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```

Output:

```
{
  ACTORS: [ 'Darshan Raval', 'Priyanka Chopra', 'Amir Khan' ],
  SINGERS: [ 'Hardy Sandhu', 'Amit Trivedi' ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your help means a lot to me